# Simple function to generate an HTML-safe string

Tags: javascript, strings, html

Sometimes, we have to do some fixing to insert a string into an HTML property. Or just to display it.

But not everything is safe! Consider the following example:

> ```
> document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = prompt('What is your name?');
> ```

This allows to introduce HTML vulnerabilities quite easily. Specially when you want to do HTML > X/HTML conversions.

So, I've came up with the following:

```js
var safetext = function(text){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerText = div.textContent = text;
    var safetext = div.innerHTML;
    div = null;
    return safetext.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
};
```

But then I realized that it could be optimized a little. That `div` is created and destroyed every single time you need a cleanup. So, I've optimized to the following:

```js
var safetext = (function(text){
    this.innerText = this.textContent = text;
    return this.innerHTML.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
}).bind(document.createElement('div'));
```

The `this` will always be the `div` we created, and will always be the same one, so, no unnecessary cleanups or anything. It is always kept in memory, since it is bound to the `this` in the anonymous function. Or isn't it?

The resulting text is a string that is safe to use in your HTML. Using the example from before:

> ```
> document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = safetext(prompt('What is your name?'));
> ```

This should show `&lt;script&gt;` if your name (for some bizarre reason) is `<script>`. Or it leaves unsafe characters behind, bound to break everything?

---

To the best of my knowledge, and based on the 200 tests where I've used it, I didn't had a single problem or hiccup.

Am I missing something? Is my code indeed returning safe HTML strings? Is the 2nd iteration really more performant?

Comment: As a general rule, if you have to ask "is this safe?" then it's not. It may cover all the attack vectors you can currently think of, but there a million more you haven't. The best solution is, in general, "Don't roll your own". Go find a widely used, extensively tested library/function/etc. and implement that.

Comment: @Zak For the purpose, it is quite overkill to use an entire library. Specially when all I wan't to make sure is that a client doesn't write `<this>` and break the whole output. I'm re-implementing an HTML > Excel XML convertion function. Also, I haven't found any library, so far, to do this. Most of what I've found is a `.replace` with a huge object with all entities, some weird replace or some close form of what I've presented (which I wasn't aware that is very used!). If you know of any library, I'm glad to check it.

Comment: It is almost never overkill when it comes to security measures in code and sanitising inputs.

Comment: @DanPantry You're right. But really, I have no idea about any library that does this kind of stuff. That is, in Javascript. In PHP, there's tons of them. Do you know any library?

Comment: Unfortunately not any that would work from a CDN

Comment: @DanPantry Mostly, what I find is ways to remove tags/attributes. What I want is to really grab a string, with whatever is in it, and put it safely. There's the Google Caja plugin to sanitize HTML. There are a few more to remove tags and attributes. But that is the oposite of what I need. And I don't mind if they don't work on a CDN. I'm open to suggestions on libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Attack**

What you are basically talking about is DOM based XSS.

But it's a self-XSS, so the only possible attack vector might be via ClickJacking (depending on the used browser).

Still, it should be defended against, especially for usability reasons.

**Proper Defense**

Here is OWASPs guide on [preventing DOM based XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). Basically, you should first HTML encode the input, and then JavaScript encode.

For your example, the second part doesn't seem necessary, just encoding `<`, `>`, `'` and `"` should be enough.

**Your Defense**

Well, your defense works.

It could be simplified a bit though. There really doesn't seem to be a need to set `this.textContent`, and I also do not see the need for `replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')` (or am I missing something here? Browser compatibility maybe?).

That would leave you with

```
var safetext = (function(text){
    this.textContent = text;
    return this.innerHTML;
}).bind(document.createElement('div'));
```

The reason this works seems to be the way `textContent` works.

But this really seems to be more of a side-effect, and it is never a good idea to use those for security related things.

**Conclusion**

Regarding performance, security, and readability, a simple replace for `<`, `>`, `'` and `"` with their HTML representation seems to be preferable to your method.

Comment: Yup, you are missing something. `this.innerText` is for Internet Explorer and Google Chrome while `this.textContent` is for Firefox and Google Chrome. I don't know where Microsoft Edge sits on this. The `replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')` is a simple trim, for Internet Explorer. I'm not sure if Internet Explorer 9 has `String.trim`, but Internet Explorer 8 doesn't. The result of this function is used on XML, which requires `&` to be encoded to `&amp;` as well. HTML doesn't like it, but won't break.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the amazing answer given by [@tim](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/49695/tim), I have to add a "bug" I have found on it.

There is a somewhat desirable side-effect to this code that makes it unusable for XML: every newline is replaced with a `<br/>`.

XML is very picky about the syntax and a stray `<br/>` showing up will be a very nasty game-breaker.

---

You can see what I mean by running this example:

```js
var safetext = (function(text){
    this.innerText = this.textContent = text;
    return this.innerHTML.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
}).bind(document.createElement('div'));

alert(safetext('A newline: \n see?'));
```

This won't happen if I do it the way [@tim](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/49695/tim) suggests.

A better implementation would be like this:

```js
var safetext = function(text){
 var table = {
  '<': 'lt',
  '>': 'gt',
  '"': 'quot',
  '\'': 'apos',
  '&': 'amp',
  '\r': '#10',
  '\n': '#13'
 };
 
 return text.toString().replace(/[<>"'\r\n&]/g, function(chr){
  return '&' + table[chr] + ';';
 });
};

alert(safetext('A newline: \n see?'));
```

This doesn't have the "bug" and it works in XML and HTML.